# Change the displaying name of user in sharepoint using SAML

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using Claim-based authentication in Sharepoint Foundation 2010 and I used following PowerShell command to register trusted token Issuer:

```
$ap = New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Name "MySTS" -Description "My STS" -UseWReply -Realm $realm -ImportTrustCertificate $cert -ClaimsMappings $map1, $map2, $map3 -SignInUrl $signinurl -IdentifierClaim $map1.InputClaimType
```

It was successful but the point is the displaying name on Sharepoint site is the value of the identifier claim. For example, if identifier claim has value: Group A, Sharepoint site will display: Group A.

So now I want to display the claim type Name instead of Group A. How could I do that?
I know my question could make you be confused, please put your investigating questions for me so I can make my question clearer.

Thank you.